# for loop through ms sql columns

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm coding in c# on webpages/razor with MS SQL database

I have a table with the following columns

- Sat1
- Sat2
- Sat3
- Sat4
- ...
- Sat25

I want to loop through each of these, and assign the value to `satAvail`

I have the following

```
for (var i = 1; i < 26; i++)
{
    satWeek = "Sat" + i;
    satAvail = item.satWeek;
}
```

I want the equivalent of `satAvail = item.Sat1;` 
I've tried a few different lines but having no joy

Comment: This is not possible (in C#)

Comment: Don't use an ORM if you want to do this. Just use a traditional query method where the results are accessed through an indexer, making this trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm clear on your actual requirement, but in general, when working with the [Database helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), if you want to access a column value resulting from a `Database.Query` or `Database.QuerySingle` call, you can either do it using dot notation or an indexer.

For example, you may get data doing this:

```
var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
var item = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE ID = 1");
```

If you know want to access the value of a column called `Sat1`, you would use `item.Sat1`. However, if the column name is represented as a variable, you would need to use an indexer instead:

```
var satWeek = "Sat" + "1";
var satAvail = item[satWeek];
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear earlier or knowing the exact terminologies - this works exactly as i wanted. brill thanks mike - you and your site has been a massive help to me

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you're using an ORM or ADO, but assuming ADO, you could use something like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                var satAvail = row[column];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

use reflection

```
var value = item.GetType().GetProperty("Sat" + i).GetValue(item, null);
```

and if you want a sum (assuming Sat1... Sat2 are integers)

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
  sum +=(int)item.GetType().GetProperty("Sat" + i).GetValue(item, null);
}
satAvail = sum;
```

or linq way :

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(1, 25)
                     .Select(x => (int)item.GetType().GetProperty("Sat" + x).GetValue(item, null))
                     .Sum();
```

Comment: Sat1 Sat2 are the column names and I'm getting Invalid column name "GetType".

Comment: @user1990727 you mean you have not a class corresponding to your table ? So my answer is far from usefull, indeed. How do you access your db ?